# How to deploy a Delphi Soap Client (.EXE) on a Windows XP/Windows 2003?

Tags: delphi, deployment, soap-client

I built a Delphi-7 Windows Application which uses some web services. The application is built in such a way that it does not require run-time DLLs. When I deployed it on a Windows 2003 server it fails while calling the web service. It results in error "Access violation at address 00c05269. Write of address 00c05269". I believe the reasons is that it needs some package to be installed. Can anybody help me to figure that out?

TIA

Comment: Honestly, there are a million and a half possible reasons for this.  Are you sure it doesn't require any DLLs?  Not even the BorlndMM/FastMM that you almost always need?  How was it deployed?  Did you try it on any other machines?  With or without Delphi installed?  An access violation is just a bad pointer, it could mean *anything*.  It's even possible that the web service library or its calling code just doesn't handle a routine error properly.  I suggest listing as much information about the environment, deployment, and steps leading up to the error as you possibly can.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I am sure it is a deployment issue. I am not sure what DLLs need to be registered on the server. Deployment notes in Delphi does not talk about this at all. Delphi app itself is working fine except that it results in this error just when it invoke the Web service method. I tested my test app on another server where Delphi Websnap DLLs are already running, and it ran just as expected. But there is no documentation as to which pieces of Delphi or SOAP are installed or registered in that machine.

Comment: I copied the whole Delphi\Bin folder into the server C:\DelphiBin and added that to System search path. The problem still exists!

Comment: try using madExcept or Eurekalog for trace the cause of error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a guess: If the client was built with D7, that runtime will AV on machines with DEP enabled. See the following link for more information:

```
 groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.webservices.soap/msg/b19f3c2681de50f4
```

You can disable DEP for just that client  (or system-wide) on the Win 2003 machine to see if that's the issue:

```
technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738483(WS.10).aspx
```

And if it is, you can download a SOAP runtime fix from here:

http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/24535

Cheers,

Bruneau

Comment: I was going to say DEP - we had this problem with a postcode SOAP lookup program on 2003. Switched DEP off for our program, everything became fine.

Comment: Great! Thanks Bruneau. DEP was the issue. It works fine with DEP turned on only for Windows Services!

Answer (score 0):

Some troubleshooting suggestions.

Can you browse to the web service from a web browser?  If not, you have a connectivity problem.

If this works, I would build a bare bones client that consumes the web service and calls a couple of methods but doesn't read from or write to any external files.

Comment: The program does not read or write files. It just calls a web service and write the return value into a TMemo object. I can access the web service from IE just fine. The same program works as expected when I ran it on a server which already had Delphi Websnap DLLs running.

Comment: Without knowing more, I suggest you use RRUZ's suggestion and use an exception logger to find out exactly what's failing to narrow down the cause.